# Should my comment have been an answer?

Tags: discussion, comments, answers

I answered [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1393280/1356425) by writing [a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1393280/http-redirect-301-permanent-vs-302-temporary#comment29230252_1393292) in reply to the comment of the answer. But then I thought that my comment is also a possible answer. So in such cases where it is better to write:

1. As an answer?
2. As a comment to the question?
3. If possible, as a comment to the answer?
4. At several places, which give the data redundancy?

Comment: What would be the comment about?

Comment: My comment is an example that I think is also an answer.

Comment: @juergend I'm guessing it is [this comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1393280/http-redirect-301-permanent-vs-302-temporary#comment29230252_1393292)

Comment: @bluefeet it is right

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your comment provides further information to the OP, who was confused about the answer. That is exactly what comments on answers are supposed to do – good job!

Given that the accepted answer has 75 up-votes, I would be cautious about adding another answer unless you think it would really benefit the community.

Answer (score 0):

If it is answering the post and no one already posted that answer, you should add it as an answer.

But if it is about asking details or more information about answer or adding some minor details about answer then it should go to a comment.